# Unable to show specific field data form MySQL db

Tags: php, session

**please ignore that it is old code im am testing**

Having an issue where by I am unable to show specific user data from my db yet I can show the row of data. I can show the username using `<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>`but if I try and throw out email for example it dosnt like it. but if I do this....

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("dmh", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
while($_SESSION = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $_SESSION['email'];
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Like I say it chucks up the row - in regards to the above mention of pulling data from the DB via `<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>` this is handled by pulling in by db_connect.php file and also my functions file.

Comment: *I know, I know:* `session_start();` is loaded. *Why do I even ask.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry I do not understand your response?

Comment: Since you are using sessions, `session_start();` is not in your posted code. If you're not loading it; do. It's required.

Comment: It is loaded at the top....

<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
 
sec_session_start();
?>

Comment: Hence my first comment ;-)

Comment: I am confused by what you are trying to advise, sorry?

Comment: Never mind, it's ok. Showing actual code helps keep the guesswork out of things.

Comment: So it loads te username from the DB yet it will not display the email or any other data fields I add into the DB which I find most odd...

Comment: Have you tried using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: No joy im afraid Fred

Comment: Try `SELECT email FROM members`

Comment: I was only using this part as a test - ideally I wanna be adding data in alongisde the the  <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>

Comment: `htmlentities` may be playing tricks on you. Can you try without it? Plus, it's always best to first assign it to a variable. I.e.: `$username=$_SESSION['username'];` etc. then you check if it's empty/set: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){ // do something }` as in `echo $username;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- So what should I be amedning  <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p> to? (Sorry)

Comment: Wait - I figured it....would this or should this work for for email too?

Comment: I can't seem to grasp exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to display more than just the username which in my current code it will only allow me to do - If I add the same statement but change it to email it dosnt like it and displays nothing.

Comment: ok so i added this.     <?php
 
 $username=$_SESSION['username'];
 if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){ 
 }
 echo ($_SESSION['username']);
 
 $email=$_SESSION['email'];
 if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && !empty($_SESSION['email'])){ 
 }
 echo ($_SESSION['email']);
 ?>
the username shows but still no email...

Comment: @Fred-ii- am i missing something here? is the db specifically not allowing it to be shown?

Comment: You echo "inside" the `{}` `$username=$_SESSION['username']; if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){ echo $username; }`

Comment: Ok so that is actually nowshowing my username and email (without the @ symbol and '.') Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still having the same issues - do you have Skype?

Comment: No, I don't have Skype. See my answer below, just unsure if that's the result you wish to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, unsure if that's the result you wish to get.

Using `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*`.

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members ");

session_start();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
  }

echo $_SESSION['email'];

echo "<hr>";

echo "TEST";

echo "<hr>";
var_dump($_SESSION['email']);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Well that cracked it!

Comment: That's great, I'm glad to hear it @user3435159

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't access the $_SESSION like that. You could try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
while($meh = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $_SESSION['email']=$meh['email'];
  echo $meh['email'];
  }
```

That way your other session variables don't get overridden when you go to this page. The only other thing that I can suggest is trying `print_r($meh);` to see what data is actually getting put in the array. If it's attaching to numbers, there's a high chance you need to access it like `echo $meh[0]`.

Comment: Seemingly this has not pulled any results - yet this has...$email=$_SESSION['email'];
 if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && !empty($_SESSION['email'])){ echo ($_SESSION['email']);
 }

Comment: So the print_r thing didn't work? That's strange. Perhaps your `$_SESSION['email'] was set somewhere else in the script, and wasn't ACTUALLY edited by this page.

Comment: no print_r didnt work unfortunately. Do you have Skype - I am trying to troubleshoot could do with another pair of eyes?

Comment: I'll go ahead and PM you the details. Or not, seeing as I can't find where to PM. My username is bobafett_bob.

Comment: Added - Just need you to confirm!